# Memsql studio showing blank screen

Tags: singlestore

I installed and started Memsql Studio 1.9.4 in single host mode. Now when I visit http://ipaddress:8080 the Memsql Studio title shows but the rest of the page is completely blank. No login box or anything. I have tried in both firefox and chrome and also tried restarting the server but still getting the blank white screen. It’s a fresh server with only Memsql installed.

The strange thing is if I open it on my phone with chrome browser set to show desktop site the page opens nicely and I see the Add New Cluster option.

**Server info**

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS x64

Kernel: 4.15.0-74-generic

File Handles: 1120 of 3075375

Processes: 137

CPU Model: Intel® Xeon® CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GH…

CPU Speed: 8x 2200 MHz (8 core)

Memory: 30 GB

**Console logs**

**Firefox**

TypeError: this._timeouts.remove is not a function 4 BrowserUsageTelemetry.jsm:303:24
Invalid chrome URI: /
LoginRecipes: getRecipes: falling back to a synchronous message for: https://www.memsql.com LoginRecipes.jsm:265:9
Invalid chrome URI: /
Invalid chrome URI: /
Invalid chrome URI: /
TypeError: this._timeouts.remove is not a function BrowserUsageTelemetry.jsm:303:24
TypeError: this._timeouts.remove is not a function BrowserUsageTelemetry.jsm:303:24
TypeError: this._timeouts.remove is not a function BrowserUsageTelemetry.jsm:303:24

**Chrome**

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at was set without the SameSite attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with SameSite=None and Secure. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at and .
(index):29 GET http://memsql.databank.net:8080/dist/app.32d38f763e7ba0415cce.js net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've engaged on the [MemSQL Forums](https://www.memsql.com/forum/t/memsql-studio-showing-blank-screen/1544/3) and the current theory is there's a block in the network.